# How do I integrate Open Live Writer?

Tags: 8

The Windows Live Writer is now open source as [Open Live Writer](https://github.com/OpenLiveWriter/OpenLiveWriter).

There used to be a [Blogapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/wlw_blogapi) module in Drupal 6 to support WLW.

As far as I know that module used XML-RPC to communicate with WLW, and other platforms such as Wordpress also use XML-RPC.

I know little about XML-RPC, so I seek suggestion on which way is more viable:

- Port that Blogapi module to Drupal 8 (how? where can I learn more about XML-RPC in Drupal?)
- Implement using other protocol, like the
  RESTful api?
- Any other suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Atom Publishing Service seems another choice.